# の and のです. What’s their semantic purpose and meaning?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-の, spoken-language

So, I've reached a spoken language topic and encountered difficulties with understanding those particles that are used in spoken language. Particularly with の. My book says that, for example, の combined with よ (部屋の中には暖かい**のよ**) means that a person is completely sure about their statement. I don't really understand the purpose of の itself in this case but I guess I just have to remember this so it's not really a problem, even though I'd like to know の's function here.

In an interrogative question the function of の is crystal clear so it's not a problem, I guess.

The problem is in understanding its meaning/function in the following sentence:

> とても気持ちがいいの。（とても気持ちがいいのです。）

The book says that の is just a short form of のです but gives zero explanations on this one, that's why I'm asking you for help.
I'd like to know its function and semantic purpose, and, if possible, I'd like you to give me literal translation of the sentence.

Thank you.

P.S. I apologize for creating this topic, because it already might exist here but I couldn't find any info about my specific situation (maybe my English is just a bit limited to understand some of the answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, …のよ is not a standard form, which is のだよ or のですよ, but a kind of slang for feminine speech or slightly vulgar manish speech.

のだ form represents your judgement/conjecture or explanation for what an instance on topic means or what lies behind it. For example, given a situation where the road is wet, you could say 雨が降ったのだ.

よ represents that there's a gap between the speaker and the listener in terms of recognition. (That doesn't mean the listener simply doesn't know the information.) However, it doesn't guarantee certainty of the speaker's recognition. In practice, implication of gap functions variously as prompting the listener to take proper actions or seeking the listener's understanding to fill the gap. After that, if you add よ to 電話してね: "Be sure to give me a call", i.e. 電話してよね, it implies that you are not trusting the listener.

> My book says that, for example, の combined with よ (部屋の中<s>に</s>は暖かいのよ) means
>   that a person is completely sure about their statement

So, that's not true. For one thing, you can imagine a preceding question "why don't they need heavy coats?".

Comment: First off, I'd like to add some info about the sentence you put in your answer. 
Here's the translation of what it says: "よ particle conveys certainty of accuracy of a sentence and can be used along with other particles" - this was the reason I said about the certainty of the statement. From your words I now understand that it's not the only function (of course if the one I talked about has a place to be at all).

Comment: Second off, I don't really understand what you meant by saying "...for what an instance on topic means". The example with **rain** and the explanation of のだ in this case is understandable, but I can't get the one I quoted. Could you give me another example for that very situation?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: >"よ particle conveys certainty of accuracy"; You can easily  find sentences like …かもしれないよ. > an instance on topic: something referred to as "it".

Comment: I still found it difficult to understand due to impossibility to imagine some kind of a situation that could imply this meaning but finally decided to read thru a dialogue and find that sentence, and here what it is: **私は冬の方が好き。冬ははやしがとてもきれいで、スキーをしに行くと、とても気持ちがいいの。** (should've done this earlier)

Comment: So, now I will try to write down what I understood. The reason winter feels good for this person is that the forest is very beautiful and she can go skiing. So... の（のだ）was used here because her feelings towards winter were caused by its features (including snow, skiing, etc.) Now I think I understand it (or at least nearly understand). Even if my idea is wrong I still have gotten a bit of purport since you had given me some explanations and all I had to do after that is just to read the dialogue and find what lies behind that phrase. Thank you.